# Creating an easy to use extension/function for Reachability (host/internet WIFI, Cellular)

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, reachability-swift

I am working on a complex app and I want to test both host in internet reachability on each ViewController that receive data from server I am currently using this library for Reachability

> https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

And I want to create an easy method or extension that check the reachability for both internet and host out of this 
I have already use the sample code from the library which is below: `import UIKit

```
import Reachability

class VC22: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var networkStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hostNameLabel: UILabel!

var reachability: Reachability?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Start reachability without a hostname intially
    setupReachability(nil, useClosures: true)
    startNotifier()

    // After 5 seconds, stop and re-start reachability, this time using a hostname
    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(5)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
        self.stopNotifier()
        self.setupReachability("http://81.28.42.42:4242/", useClosures: true)
        self.startNotifier()

        let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(5)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
            self.stopNotifier()
            self.setupReachability("invalidhost", useClosures: true)
            self.startNotifier()            }

    }
}

func setupReachability(_ hostName: String?, useClosures: Bool) {
    hostNameLabel.text = hostName != nil ? hostName : "No host name"

    print("--- set up with host name: \(hostNameLabel.text!)")

    let reachability = hostName == nil ? Reachability() : Reachability(hostname: hostName!)
    self.reachability = reachability

    if useClosures {
        reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability)
            }
        }
        reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability)
            }
        }
    } else {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VC22.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
    }
}

func startNotifier() {
    print("--- start notifier")
    do {
        try reachability?.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        networkStatus.textColor = .red
        networkStatus.text = "Unable to start\nnotifier"
        return
    }
}

func stopNotifier() {
    print("--- stop notifier")
    reachability?.stopNotifier()
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    reachability = nil
}

func updateLabelColourWhenReachable(_ reachability: Reachability) {
    print("\(reachability.description) - \(reachability.currentReachabilityString)")
    if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
        self.networkStatus.textColor = .green
    } else {
        self.networkStatus.textColor = .blue
    }

    self.networkStatus.text = reachability.currentReachabilityString
}

func updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(_ reachability: Reachability) {
    print("\(reachability.description) - \(reachability.currentReachabilityString)")

    self.networkStatus.textColor = .red

    self.networkStatus.text = reachability.currentReachabilityString
}


func reachabilityChanged(_ note: Notification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable {
        updateLabelColourWhenReachable(reachability)
    } else {
        updateLabelColourWhenNotReachable(reachability)
    }
}

deinit {
    stopNotifier()
}

}
```

this works fine but I just need a boolean to tell me if it is connected or not that could be reusable through the app

**UPDATE** currently I am using below class:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .connectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

and use in viewControllers like below :

```
 if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        print("Internet connection OK")

      JSONParseFunction()

} else {
    print("Internet connection FAILED")
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "You are not connect to internet", message: "please check you connectivity", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

This way I just check for internet I need to check both Host and Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason for not just dropping this in your `AppDelegate` and subscribe to the observer there instead of doing it on a specific vc?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        prepareReachabilityObserver()
        return true
    }

    private func prepareReachabilityObserver() {
        AppDelegate.reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Not reachable")
            }
        }

        do {
            try AppDelegate.reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }
    }
```

On the `host verification extension` part, I'd probably go with something like:

```
extension UIViewController {
    internal func isReachable() -> Bool {
            //this is the function you already have.
    }
}
```

which you can then use in every viewcontroller by doing

```
self.isReachable() //'self' is a UIViewController in this case.
```

Other than this, I'm having trouble understanding your question, since you seem to already have this solved.

EDIT: I think I understand your question, now. You want to check both *if* you're reachable and if the hostname you pass around is also reachable.
I don't think it's the best idea to handle both at the same time, since one is a Reachability issue ('can I get an outgoing connection?') and the other one is a connection issue ('can I get a response from this remote place?' or 'Does this request timeout?').

The way I currently handle it is Reachability in something like the AppDelegate and then handling the timeout on a request-by-request manner (which you can then generalize within the network-stuff scope).
To be more specific:
`AppDelegate` sets Reachability. Then I have a `RequestsManager` that handles service calls with a configured `timeout`.

Then you can do something like:

```
RequestManager.makeRequest("https://an.endpoint.of.yours",
        onSuccess: {},
        onFailure: { //Here goes your timeout behaviour.
})
```

*Where do I pass the hostname?*
I think that's an unneeded behaviour, to be honest. You don't `try to open door` *and then* you `open door`. You just try and see if you're successful. Here's the same. You try to make a request, does it succeed? Awesome. Does it not? Handle accordingly. What do you (The app) care if the failure was because the endpoint was down or because you don't have a working data plan or network's down? The request times out either way, and that's what you care about.

Again, this is all assuming I actually understood you, which I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You should import Reachability in your AppDelegate file.
`import Reachability` like you already did in your example. Also, I heavily updated the answer because I wasn't sure I fully understood the question. Please confirm.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth answer